# Failing to Use Docker to Run a Project

Tags: python, node.js, docker

So I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/isislab/CSAW-CTF-2017-Quals/tree/master/web/orange) project using docker.

I followed the standard docker protocol:

```
docker build -t orange .
docker run -p 8080:8080 orange
```

I used the following command to check that the docker image was indeed created.

```
docker image ls
```

However, after running these commands, there is still no site running on localhost:8080. Any tips on troubleshooting this?

EDIT: After using the right port, I'm getting a directory listing instead of an actual site. [Directory listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqJQN.png)

Comment: wrong port? I see the exposed one is 9999, not 8080

Comment: oh.. thanks. Now I'm just getting a directory listing though; it doesn't run serve.sh as the entry point.

Comment: Since there is a docker-compose file, why don't you just run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up` Then you should find the server on localhost:9999

Comment: That worked, thanks. If you want, you can answer the question so I can upvote it and designate it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the repository, it seems that the exposed port is 9999 and not 8080. Also, it looks like you can use docker-compose, that is, you can run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

to spin up the server. You should then be able to reach it at localhost:9999

Comment: you can also use `docker-compose up --build`